# Change the visibility of Divs, using jQuery and html select upon webpage loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I Have this `html/jQuery` module and bootstrap classes, that changes the display of `divs`, if the select option changes.

This works without any trouble. Now I want to change just a little the behavior:

Since I use `.change` jQuery method, It only changes the display when the user changes the selected option. But when The page is loaded all items are displayed no matter if I "preselect" an option using selected attribute.

How can I change that only show the `divs` of the "preselected" option, in this case for example:
`<option value="periodo-1" selected>1° period</option>` to show on page load only the `.periodo-1 items`, instead of all.

```js
$('#seleccionperiodo').change(function(){
        $('.bloque-materia').closest('.col-md-4').hide({easing : 'linear'});
        
        $('.' + $(this).val()).closest('.col-md-4').show('20');
      });
```

```css
.bloque-materia {
    background: gray;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="seleccionperiodo" class="periodo">
                            <option value="bloque-materia">All</option>
                                <option value="periodo-1" selected>1° period</option>
                                <option value="periodo-2">2° period</option>
                                <option value="periodo-3">3° period</option>
                                <option value="periodo-4">4° period</option>
                        </select>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-1">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 1</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-2">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 2</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-1">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 3</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-3">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 4</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-3">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 5</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-4">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 6</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-4">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 7</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-1">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 8</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create function to change the visibility of `Divs` by selected value  of `selectbox` and then call the function when the page is loading.

Here is working snippet:

```js
function changeDiv(value) {
    $('.bloque-materia').closest('.col-md-4').hide({ easing: 'linear' });

    $('.' + value).closest('.col-md-4').show('20');
}

var value = $('#seleccionperiodo').val();
changeDiv(value);

$('#seleccionperiodo').change(function () {
    changeDiv($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.bloque-materia {
    background: gray;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="seleccionperiodo" class="periodo">
                            <option value="bloque-materia">All</option>
                                <option value="periodo-1" selected>1° period</option>
                                <option value="periodo-2">2° period</option>
                                <option value="periodo-3">3° period</option>
                                <option value="periodo-4">4° period</option>
                        </select>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-1">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 1</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-2">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 2</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-1">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 3</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-3">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 4</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-3">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 5</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-4">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 6</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-4">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 7</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="bloque-materia periodo-1">
     <h2 class="topic">Topic 8</h2>
     <div class="description">
         <p>My fancy Desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```